# ORA-00904: Invalid column name on a correlated subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance, ora-00904, oracle8i

I'm having a problem correlating a subquery on Oracle 8i

That subquery gives me an ORA-00904: Invalid column name, I don't understand why. Shouldn't it work?

```
SELECT
    HIST_FA.HIFA_PLAN_CODIGO                                                AS FE_CODIGO_PLANTEL,
    HIST_FA.HIFA_NUMERO                                                     AS FE_NUMERO_CONTROL,
    HIST_FA.HIFA_FECHA                                                      AS FE_FECHA_HORA_EMISION,
    HIST_FA.HIFA_DEST_CLIE_CODIGO                                           AS FE_CODIGO_CLIENTE,
    --  . . . a bunch of other columns . . .
FROM
    VFA_HIST_FA HIST_FA,
    VFA_HIST_ITEMS_FA HIST_ITEMS_FA,
    (
        SELECT
            HIRF_HIIF_HIFA_NUMERO                                           AS FE_NUMERO_CONTROL,
            SUM(DECODE(HIRF_RETE_CODIGO, 0, HIRF_MONTO))                    AS FE_MONTO_ENTREGADO,
            SUM(DECODE(HIRF_RETE_CODIGO, 5, HIRF_MONTO))                    AS FE_IMPUESTO_UNICO,
            SUM(DECODE(HIRF_RETE_CODIGO, 6, HIRF_MONTO))                    AS FE_MARGEN_COMERCIALIZACION
        FROM
            VFA_HIST_ITEMS_RETENC_FA
        WHERE
            HIRF_HIIF_HIFA_NUMERO = HIST_FA.HIFA_NUMERO
        GROUP BY
            HIRF_HIIF_HIFA_NUMERO
    ) PP  
WHERE
    HIST_FA.HIFA_NUMERO = HIST_ITEMS_FA.HIIF_HIFA_NUMERO;
```

Of course, I can do this at the main `WHERE`, but then it scans all rows in the inner one.

```
HIST_FA.HIFA_NUMERO = PP.FE_NUMERO_CONTROL
```

So, not an option, since the query becomes everlasting.

Best regards!

Comment: Oracle 8i? Wow... that brings memories.

Comment: Extended support for Oracle 8i ended in 2006.  Surely the time passed more than a decade ago when you should have upgraded.

Comment: @TheImpaler LOL

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know, but it's not me. It's a dinosaur customer, I can't do anything but work with it

Comment: @JuanDiego And with those memories, now I want to go for beers. Sigh.

Comment: Does the error message indicate which line is getting the error? Sometimes is lists the line with the error and puts and * under the problem character.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Alias Name for the column name 
HIRF_HIIF_HIFA_NUMERO            AS **FE_NUMERO_CONTROL**
to some other name and try again.

Comment: It does not work, unless I'm not doing it well, could you please be more specific?? I mean, I did change the alias and still, infamous ORA00904.